# Superset - Use custom druid dimensions as filter not working

Tags: apache-superset

I'm using custom dimension ( type : lookup ) as another column in the data source.
the data load to Superset table perfectly and I can see the lookup values.
I've added filter box and selected the lookup column to filter on  along with the table slice to my dashboard but when I choose any option in the select box I get "no data returned" on the table, I verified that chosen options that have results on the table

[without any filtering I can see the data for the custom lookup columns in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CMzX.png)

[when filtering with one of the columns that for sure has results in the table ( the first result ) no data is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkLs7.png)

furthermore, when exploring the table and try to add a filter from the left panel, I can't see any data on the selectbox
[as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uab93.png)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. I tested [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/pull/4740). It provides support for a lookup with and extract function. This is not the best solution given you will have to have two lookups in order to also see the lookup values. However, it does function. Once the PR is merged into a release this will be more widely available. Here is an example of the extractFn lookup I used. Basically, I make two new dimensions `country_group` for grouping by and `country_group_filter` for filtering on. This is a hack for now. I hope to be able to implement a fix and create a PR. I won't have time to tackle this until June 2018 though.

```
{
  "dimension": "country",
  "outputName": "country_group_filter",
  "outputType": "STRING",
  "retainMissingValue": true,
  "type": "selector",
  "extractionFn": {
    "type": "lookup",
    "lookup": {
      "map": {
        "Algeria": "EMEA",
        "Faroe Islands": "EMEA",
        "Luxembourg": "EMEA",
        "Andorra": "EMEA",
        "Cameroon": "EMEA",
        "Burkina Faso": "EMEA",
        "Benin": "EMEA",
        "Bahrain": "EMEA",
        "Aland Islands": "EMEA",
        "Australia": "AU/NZ",
        "Iceland": "EMEA",
        "Cape Verde": "EMEA"
      },
      "type": "map",
      "isOneToOne": false
    }
  }
}
```